# How to force an application window to be automatically maximized after starting the application?

Tags: window, xdotool, maximized, wmctrl

I tried to use Docky, then I removed it and after that my browser (Chromium) can't be opened in maximum height, every time I should maximize it myself. (XFCE desktop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How to startup an application (any) maximized

Starting an application via the script below, you can force *any* application`*` to startup maximized. If you either replace the *main* command in (a copy of-) your `.desktop` file by the command to run the script (see further below how to do that) or add it as a quicklist shortcut, you can achieve exactly what you want.

(*`*` Some applications have a fixed, unchangeable windowsize, some windows open a new tab in a possibly already opened window*)

#### About the script

The script runs with the command:

```
python3 /path/to/script <application>
```

The script:

- first runs the command to open the application
- to prevent timing issues, it then waits for the application's (new) window to appear (by finding a match between its `pid` and the `id` of the corresponding window) in the output of the `wmctrl -lp` -command (for only 15 seconds, to prevent an infinite loop)
- Once the window appears, it maximizes the window with the command:

  ```
  xdotool windowsize <window_id> 100% 100%
  ```

*The code*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import getpass
import time
import sys

app = sys.argv[1]

user = getpass.getuser()
get = lambda x: subprocess.check_output(x).decode("utf-8")
ws1 = get(["wmctrl", "-lp"]); t = 0
subprocess.Popen(app)
while t < 30:      
    ws2 = [(w.split()[2], w.split()[0]) for w in get(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).splitlines() if not w in ws1]
    procs = sum([[(w[1], p) for p in get(["ps", "-u", user]).splitlines() \
              if app[:15].lower() in p.lower() and w[0] in p] for w in ws2], [])
    if len(procs) > 0:
        subprocess.call(["xdotool", "windowsize", "-sync", procs[0][0] , "100%", "100%"])
        break
    time.sleep(0.5)
    t = t+1
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `run_maximized.py`
3. Now edit your `.desktop` file:

   - Copy the global `.desktop` file locally:

     ```
     cp /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
     ```

#### XFCE version:

4. open the file with gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
   ```

   Browse to the line:

   ```
   Exec=chromium-browser %U
   ```

   (which is the first line, starting with `Exec=`

   Change it into:

   ```
   Exec=python3 /path/to/script.py chromium-browser
   ```

   where you need to replace `/path/to/script.py` by the actual path.
5. Log out and back in. From now on, your Chromium launcher will open Chromium maximized.

#### Unity version:

4. open the file with gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
   ```

   Browse to the line:

   ```
   Actions=NewWindow;Incognito;TempProfile;
   ```

   Change it into:

   ```
   Actions=NewWindow;Incognito;TempProfile;divider1;Open maximized;
   ```

   The add to the very bottom of the file the section below:

   ```
   [Desktop Action Open maximized]
   Name=Open maximized
   Exec=python3 /path/to/script.py chromium-browser
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;

   [Desktop Action divider1]
   Name=.....................................
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;
   ```

   where you need to replace `/path/to/script.py` by the actual path.
5. Log out and back in. From now on, your Chromium launcher looks like:

   [image]

### Important note

In a `.desktop` file, you *must* use absolute paths; `~` won't work for example. This counts for `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications`, `~/.local/share/applications` as well as commands in Startup Applications (which are actually called by `.desktop` files in `~/.config/autostart`).

Comment: The problem fixed by itself after rebooting.

Comment: I tried to do it with Thunar - didn't work: I edited /usr/share/applications/Thunar.desktop, changed this line: Exec=python3 ~/script.py thunar %F

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% foolproof, but a much simpler approach is to modify the `Exec=` line in an existing `.desktop` file and run `xdotool search --sync` there directly. This waits for the window to be mapped, and avoids hard-coded delays. Not to disparage the hard work [Jacob put into that Python script](https://askubuntu.com/a/698663/681614), but it *does* seem exorbitant for what is essentially a one-liner in the shell.

Here's an example, using [Alacarte](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/alacarte/-/issues/15) (a GUI editor for the system menus):

```ini
Exec=sh -c 'alacarte & xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class alacarte windowsize 100%% 100%%'
```

Note the `&` which—critically—puts the application in the background. Also note that `%` [must be escaped as `%%`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html) within the `Exec` key.

By "not 100% foolproof" I mean the process of editing `.desktop` files by hand is very typo-prone, and you're unlikely to get a good error message from anywhere if you mess something up. You'll usually just get… nothing. The utility `dex` (available in the "universe" repository) can run a `.desktop` file directly from the shell and its `-v` option may help with debugging.

It *is* possible to edit the `.desktop` file directly in `/usr/share/applications` (as root), but it's probably best to use Alacarte or [MenuLibre](https://bluesabre.org/projects/menulibre) to create one in `~/.local/share/applications`, so your changes aren't overwritten by future package update. Both should be available from the "universe" repository on Ubuntu and derivatives.

Lastly, if you edit the `.desktop` file by hand, run `update-desktop-database` in the containing directory to update the cache, otherwise it may seem like nothing happened.

Comment: If `windowsize 100%% 100%%` doesn't actually make the window fill the full viewport, try 110% or 120%. I had this problem with certain apps in elementary OS, and all I can figure is the way Gala (the elementary OS window manager) draws drop shadows is interfering with `xdotool windowsize` somehow. The workaround is good enough that I don't think I'll do any further research into it.