# How to set Firefox to open as a maximized window?

Tags: firefox

Whenever I open Firefox it doesn't open as a maximized window, just a rectangle. At first I didn't care but after some use it's been getting annoying and now I'm trying to fix it. I tried following [this guide](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1118937) but to no avail.

(Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS - Firefox 69.0 64-bit)

Comment: There's the `R-Kiosk` extension and the `-fullscreen` argument: https://askubuntu.com/questions/36287/how-to-start-firefox-in-fullscreen-mode - BTW I'm not sure that this is the correct link, it's something about a corrupt xul.

Comment: Go to Preferences > General and set Restore previous session. Then when reopening FF will restore what was set when you closed it.

Comment: Here's a way for any GUI application: https://askubuntu.com/a/698663/248158

Comment: Strange, because Firefox should remember its last position. For me, it always starts full screen, which is how it was when I last closed it.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's too late, but maybe for others who look for this, it is helpful.

Based on this [link](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/04/24/firefox-not-remembering-the-last-window-size-this-may-fix-it/), it's maybe because of **resistFingerprinting** config.

Just go to *about:config* search for *privacy.resistFingerprinting* and change its value to false, then restart firefox.